# How to access interfaces.h defined in the app from plugins residing in other git repositories?

Tags: c++, git, qt

## Summary

Qt offers interfaces to extend applications with the use of plugins. This interfaces tend to be defined in headers in the app and included in the plugins. If I have different git repos for the app and the plugins, how can I include the interfaces in the plugins in a scalable way?

## Example

Let's use the [Plug & Paint example](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-tools-plugandpaint-example.html) from Qt's documentation. This is the main app and defines the interfaces for `BrushInterface`, `ShapeInterface` and `FilterInterface` in interfaces.h.

```
// plugandpaint/interfaces.h
// (...)
class BrushInterface
{
// (...)
};

class ShapeInterface
{
   // (...)
};

class FilterInterface
{
    // (...)
};
// (...)
```

The [Plug & Paint Basic Tools example](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-tools-plugandpaintplugins-basictools-example.html) defines a plugin that complies with those interfaces. To do this it has to include the interfaces.h from the app in its plugin class definition.

```
// basictools/basictoolsplugin.h
// (...)
#include <plugandpaint/interfaces.h>

class BasicToolsPlugin : public QObject,
                         public BrushInterface,
                         public ShapeInterface,
                         public FilterInterface
// (...)
```

The example assumes that the plugin resides 2 subfolders below the main app, and adds the following line to the plugin's .pro file to include its headers.

```
INCLUDEPATH  += ../..
```

## Question

Is this good practice? Should I follow this convention and always clone the plugins git repos 2 subfolders below the app "hardcoding" the `INCLUDEPATH` as `../..`?

One alternative would be to have a copy of the interfaces.h file in the plugins, but then changes in the "original" file may break the plugins. Is there a way to have different but compatible interfaces.h files between the app and a plugin? For example, if the interfaces.h file residing in the app repo adds/deletes interfaces not used by the plugin, would that affect the use of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use a common repository for the header interfaces in your specific case, as you are both the creator and the consumer of your plugins. IIRC, that's what I did in a similar application a  long time ago (app and plugins would use this additional repository as a submodule).

For third party users, the headers should be installed after the application is installed and this path should be set when building your plugins (CMake using a MyApp.cmake for instance).

So two solutions, depending on the usage of the interface.